# Passando valor de uma variáven VARCHAR no comando WHERE IN

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

boa noite.

Tenho a seguinte procedure de exemplo

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_listaFuncionarios
@nome_dept varchar(50)
as
SELECT * FROM Funcionarios WHERE nome_departamento IN (@nome_dept)
```

Se, durante a chamada da procedure quiser passar dois valores simultâneos tais como : Vendas e Marketing.

Chamei a procedure dessa forma

```
EXEC sp_listaFuncionarios '''Marketing'',''Vendas'''
```

Porém não retorna nada.
Fiz um teste verificando o valor que é gravado em um variável

```
'Marketing','Vendas'
```

Pegando esse valor e passando direto na consulta, retorna os valores tranquilamente.

Alguma sugestão do que posso fazer no código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma procedure que converte uma array em uma lista de palavras.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ArrayToString]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ToString Varchar(1000)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #TempList (Strings Varchar(50))

    DECLARE @IDs varchar(50), @Pos int

    SET @ToString = LTRIM(RTRIM(@ToString))+ ','
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @ToString, 1)

    IF REPLACE(@ToString, ',', '') <> ''
    BEGIN
        WHILE @Pos > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @IDs = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@ToString, @Pos - 1)))
            IF @IDs <> ''
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #TempList (Strings) VALUES (CAST(@IDs AS Varchar(50))) --Use Appropriate conversion
            END
            SET @ToString = RIGHT(@ToString, LEN(@ToString) - @Pos)
            SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @ToString, 1)

        END
    END 

    Select Strings From #TempList
    Drop Table #TempList

END
```

Em sua consulta faça algo parecido com isto:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_listaFuncionarios
@nome_dept varchar(50)
as

    CREATE TABLE #TempList (dpt varchar(50))
    Insert Into #TempList (dpt) 
        Exec sp_ArrayToString @nome_dept


SELECT * FROM Funcionarios WHERE nome_departamento IN (select dpt from #TempList)
```

Passe o parametro assim:

```
EXEC sp_listaFuncionarios 'Marketing,Vendas'
```

Comment: Não esqueça de após usar a #TempList dar um drop. Drop Table #TempList

Comment: Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 4):

Provavelmente seu erro está na chamada, tente da seguinte maneira:

```
EXEC sp_listaFuncionarios @nome_dept = 'Marketing'
```

Você terá problemas para passar o parâmetro com estas aspas. Talvez seja melhor filtrar pelo id do departamento se essa coluna existir, dessa forma:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_listaFuncionarios
@id_dept varchar(50)
as
SELECT * FROM Funcionarios WHERE nome_departamento IN (' + @id_dept + ')'

EXEC sp_listaFuncionarios @id_dept = '1,2,3'
```